# In EmberJS, using glob routes, when I transitionToRoute, I get commas instead of slashes

Tags: routes, ember.js

my routes are...

```
this.route("websites", { path: '/' });
this.route('websites', { path: 'tags/*tags' });
```

Note the globbed, *tags. As I change content I want to transition to a new url, so I...

```
this.transitionToRoute('websites', this.get('content').mapProperty('name'))
```

in my controller, where content is obviously an array of Ember objects with a name property. It works great but unfortunately the URL I get is...

```
/tags/ember,javascript
```

instead of

```
/tags/ember/javascript
```

Is this a bug in emberJS? Or I am doing something wrong?

Been fighting with this for days, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for reading, but how can I show that? Not sure I can demonstrate how URLs change in jsfiddle.